# How to update values in while loop

Tags: sql, sql-server, while-loop

I have a column (tempColumn) in table. Table contains 100 records.

So I want to iterate the records and check that columns contain numeric values.

If that column does not contain a numeric value then update the column value as 0.,

SQL query-

```
   WHILE (select Original_Prn from #tblEOD2) is not null
                BEGIN
                    set @count = Original_Prn;
                    if ISNUMERIC(@count)=0
                        update #tblEOD2 Original_Prn =0  where Original_Prn=@count

   END
```

I this scenario, how do I update the same column in SQL sever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need a loop

```
update #tblEOD2 set Original_Prn=0  where ISNUMERIC(Original_Prn)=0
```